# Migration not filling out "networks": {}, field in .json file

Tags: truffle

When I run `truffle migrate` all my .json files in my build/contracts directory are missing their network field. Im trying to deploy to testrpc.

This is my truffle.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  },
  mocha: {
    bail: true
  }
};
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your migration file?